# Problemas com dpkg no Linux Mint

Tags: linux, mint, dpkg

Acho que desinstalei algum pacote que alguma aplicação precisava, e acho que isso gerou um problema que não consigo solucionar. Estou utilizando o Mint. Já tentei fazer o upgrade do sistema mas esse erro impede que eu faça isso. O que devo fazer para solucionar o problema?

Tentei reconfigurar o `dpkg` com `(sudo dpkg --configure -a)`, mas gerou:

```
Configurando man-db (2.6.3-3) ...
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: erro ao processar man-db (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de debhelper:
 debhelper depende de man-db (>= 2.5.1-1); porém:
  Pacote man-db não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar debhelper (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Configurando samba-common (2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1) ...
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: erro ao processar samba-common (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de smbclient:
 smbclient depende de samba-common (= 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1); porém:
  Pacote samba-common não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar smbclient (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de libnss-winbind:amd64:
 libnss-winbind:amd64 depende de samba-common (= 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1); porém:
  Pacote samba-common não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar libnss-winbind:amd64 (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de samba-common-bin:
 samba-common-bin depende de samba-common (>= 2:3.4.0~pre1-2); porém:
  Pacote samba-common não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar samba-common-bin (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: erro ao processar cryptsetup (--configure):
 O pacote está em um estado de inconsistência muito ruim - você deveria
 reinstalá-lo antes de tentar uma configuração.
Configurando phonon:i386 (4:4.7.0really4.6.0-0ubuntu2) ...
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: erro ao processar phonon:i386 (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de libpam-winbind:amd64:
 libpam-winbind:amd64 depende de samba-common (= 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1); porém:
  Pacote samba-common não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar libpam-winbind:amd64 (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de samba:
 samba depende de samba-common (= 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1); porém:
  Pacote samba-common não está configurado ainda.
 samba depende de samba-common-bin; porém:
  Pacote samba-common-bin não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar samba (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de winbind:
 winbind depende de samba-common (= 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1); porém:
  Pacote samba-common não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar winbind (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 man-db
 debhelper
 samba-common
 smbclient
 libnss-winbind:amd64
 samba-common-bin
 cryptsetup
 phonon:i386
 libpam-winbind:amd64
 samba
 winbind
```

Comment: Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: @LucasNunes tive que remover pacote por pacote... deu um trabalhão mas deu certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimente desinstalar os pacotes que originaram o problema. Por exemplo,

```
 # sudo apt-get remove samba-common-bin
```

Atualize o repositório

```
# sudo apt-get update
```

E reconfigure os pacotes

```
# sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Caso as alternativas acima não funcionem, experimente limpar a pasta /boot e instale os pacotes usando o APT.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema no Ubuntu 14.04. Já tentei a solução acima mas não obtive exito. No meu caso aparece uma lista grande de pacotes quebrados. Vou ter que deletar todos?

Answer (score 1):

Já passei por isso também.
Tenta:

```
sudo apt-get clean && apt-get update
```

Senão funcionar tenta:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 

sudo apt-get update
```